# Autorun WAV files on VLC

Tags: raspbian-buster

Is there a simple way to automatically have a specific WAV file play using VLC on power up?

I'm running Raspberry Pi OS (32-Bit), dated 20210507 on a Raspberry Pi 2 and I've already verified that the WAV file plays correctly by simply manually playing it on VLC.

Thanks!

phil

Comment: Please edit your question to show the command you used to play the WAV file correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cron` to accomplish this:

Create an entry in user pi's `crontab` to play your chosen file under the `@reboot` scheduling option; for example:

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 30; /usr/bin/vlc /path/to/yourWAVfile.wav 2>/home/pi/vlcerror.log
```

The `sleep` command will defer execution of `vlc` for 30 seconds. This is added to allow any services required by `vlc` to start before invoking `vlc` itself. Note that 30 seconds is *intended* to be conservative, and the actual `sleep` time required is system-dependent. In other words, feel free to experiment with this value - it may even be completely unnecessary!

The `2>/home/pi/vlcerror.log` is a *redirection* that sends any error messages from `vlc` to the designated file for post-mortem troubleshooting.

You can refresh your knowledge of VLC's command line repertoire to expand your choices beyond a single WAV file - [perhaps by reading the VLC documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/Command-line_interface/), and perhaps [this guide](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/).